# Shifting from TCP port to Unix socket in redis

Tags: redis

Can I change tcp port to unix socket in redis.conf **without restarting the redis server**? If so, can you please outline the steps.

---

The traditional way to do it is as follows:

1) Comment `port 6379` in redis.conf

2) Uncomment `/var/run/redis/redis.sock` and `unixsocketperm 770` in redis.conf

3) Change `unixsocketperm 770` to `unixsocketperm 777` (or preferably `755`)

4) Restart the redis server

5) Inside the app, set connectionpool to `redis.ConnectionPool(connection_class=redis.UnixDomainSocketConnection, path='/var/run/redis/redis.sock', db=0)`

Comment: AFAIK, you CANNOT do that. Why not restart it?

Comment: @for_stack: well our previous exchange has me a bit spooked about restarting, so was wondering if it's possible to circumvent it altogether for this particular case.

Comment: You can shut down Redis, and backup the RDB file. After that, restart Redis :)